# $.each is repeating the same entries multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, object

I'm building an App in Phonegap (cordova), and including jquery. For some reason if I add any html elements to `append` while in `$.each`, it starts to duplicate all of the entries in my object.

```js
var prof = {"charID":1,"powers":{"125":{"powerID":125,"name":"Cosmic Awareness","rank":100,"id":234,"charID":1},"151":{"powerID":151,"name":"Body Resistance","rank":20,"id":4,"charID":1},"201":{"powerID":201,"name":"Mass Increase","rank":36,"id":2,"charID":1},"202":{"powerID":202,"name":"Phasing","rank":26,"id":10,"charID":1},"237":{"powerID":237,"name":"Gravity Generation","rank":36,"id":3,"charID":1}},"talents":{"2":{"talentID":2,"name":"Thrown Weapons","rank":1,"id":229,"charID":1},"9":{"talentID":9,"name":"Weapons Specialist","rank":1,"id":228,"charID":1},"10":{"talentID":10,"name":"Martial Arts A","rank":1,"id":4,"charID":1},"13":{"talentID":13,"name":"Martial Arts D","rank":1,"id":5,"charID":1},"16":{"talentID":16,"name":"Thrown Objects","rank":1,"id":230,"charID":1},"29":{"talentID":29,"name":"Detective/Espionage","rank":1,"id":2,"charID":1},"36":{"talentID":36,"name":"Computers","rank":1,"id":1,"charID":1},"39":{"talentID":39,"name":"Sleight of Hand","rank":1,"id":250,"charID":1},"50":{"talentID":50,"name":"Leadership","rank":1,"id":3,"charID":1},"51":{"talentID":51,"name":"Zero-G Training","rank":1,"id":6,"charID":1},"52":{"talentID":52,"name":"Zero-G Combat","rank":1,"id":7,"charID":1}}};

$.each(prof.powers, function(id, powa) {
  $('#pvPowerList div').append('<div class="row">');
  $('#pvPowerList div').append(powa.name); 
  $('#pvPowerList div').append('</div>');   
});
```

```css
.row {display:block; clear:both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pvPowerList">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If I remove the html, and only do `$('#pvPowerList div').append(powa.name);` then it lists them out correctly.

What am I donig wrong? why is it acting like that?

Comment: OK, on further study, I've noted it's specifically when I use `<div class="row">`

Comment: Even more specifically, whenever I try to add `<div>`. It even seems to be fine with the `</div>`. I am so confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each iteration you are adding a `div` into `#pvPowerList`, then you select all the divs again, including the one you just created and append to that one and so on.
Also, `.append` doesn't support leaving tags open.
The following should fix your issue:

```js
var prof = {"charID":1,"powers":{"125":{"powerID":125,"name":"Cosmic Awareness","rank":100,"id":234,"charID":1},"151":{"powerID":151,"name":"Body Resistance","rank":20,"id":4,"charID":1},"201":{"powerID":201,"name":"Mass Increase","rank":36,"id":2,"charID":1},"202":{"powerID":202,"name":"Phasing","rank":26,"id":10,"charID":1},"237":{"powerID":237,"name":"Gravity Generation","rank":36,"id":3,"charID":1}},"talents":{"2":{"talentID":2,"name":"Thrown Weapons","rank":1,"id":229,"charID":1},"9":{"talentID":9,"name":"Weapons Specialist","rank":1,"id":228,"charID":1},"10":{"talentID":10,"name":"Martial Arts A","rank":1,"id":4,"charID":1},"13":{"talentID":13,"name":"Martial Arts D","rank":1,"id":5,"charID":1},"16":{"talentID":16,"name":"Thrown Objects","rank":1,"id":230,"charID":1},"29":{"talentID":29,"name":"Detective/Espionage","rank":1,"id":2,"charID":1},"36":{"talentID":36,"name":"Computers","rank":1,"id":1,"charID":1},"39":{"talentID":39,"name":"Sleight of Hand","rank":1,"id":250,"charID":1},"50":{"talentID":50,"name":"Leadership","rank":1,"id":3,"charID":1},"51":{"talentID":51,"name":"Zero-G Training","rank":1,"id":6,"charID":1},"52":{"talentID":52,"name":"Zero-G Combat","rank":1,"id":7,"charID":1}}};

var target = $('#pvPowerList > div');
$.each(prof.powers, function(id, powa) {
  target.append('<div class="row">' + powa.name + '</div>');
});
```

```css
.row {display:block; clear:both;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="pvPowerList">
  <div>
  </div>
</div>
```